# ggplot: panel of bar charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have the following data set:

```
Year, Height, Width, Weight
1990, 5, 45, 190
2000, 7, 77, 210
2010, 2, 20, 150
```

I would like to plot a single column of bar charts with a plot for **height**, **width**, and **weight**. In each bar chart, the values would be plotted for each year. So, say the top bar plot in my column of bar charts is **height** it would show the values 5, 7, and 2 with the years 1990, 2000, and 2010 on the x-axis.

I have figured out how to have a single column of bar plots with each bar plot representing a year:

```
data <- read.csv("../data/MyData.csv")
data.m <- melt(data, id.vars = "Year")

p <- ggplot(data.m, aes(variable, value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~ Year, ncol=1)
print(p)
```

In this case, my variables – **height**, **weight**, and **width** – are on the x-axis of each bar plot. Nevertheless, I simply cannot get my head around how to do convert this so that **Year** is on the x-axis. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you tried mapping `Year` to `x` argument of `ggplot` in `aes` then facetting by `variable` instead ?

Comment: Ah, that's it. Thanks @Titolondon! Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, map correct value to the aesthetic you want. It is easier to do a non-faceted plot to check if everything ok before faceting

```
p <- ggplot(data.m, aes(x = Year, y = value)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
     facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol=1)
```